# Redirect email in Hotmail/Outlook.com with date rules

Tags: outlook.com

I want to add some rules to redirect to my Hotmail email messages. For example a redirect in some determinate period of time:

> redirect from test@test.net to test2@test2.net from 9:00 am until 6:30 pm Between Monday and Friday (office hours)

Other days don't redirect.

Is there a way that I can do something similar?